# In-App Billing Plugin 6.7.0: System.NullReferenceException: Current Activity is null when I use PurchaseAsync in my Android project

Tags: c#, xamarin

I get the following exception when I use PurchaseAsync in my Android project:

```
  var purchase = await billing.PurchaseAsync(productId, ItemType.InAppPurchase);
```

> excep {System.NullReferenceException: Current Activity is null, ensure
> that the MainActivity.cs file is configuring Xamarin.Essentials in
> your source code so the In App Billing can use it.    at
> Plugin.InAppBilling.InAppBillingImplementation.get_Activity() in
> D:\a\1\…}

[Image exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r9WJ.png)

But I don't use Xamarin.Essentials anymore. I migrated from In-App Billing Plugin 4.0.2 to 6.7.0 and I use Microsoft.Maui.Essentials now. I have only tested In-App Billing Plugin 6.7.0 in my Android project, I have not yet tested in my iOS project.

[Image Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K71RP.png)

What should I do in my Activity1.cs?

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
    //  Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, bundle); old code from version 4.0.2
```

What should I do to avoid the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xamarin.Essentials is for the Xamarin.Forms project, and for the Maui project, you can try to use the following code in the **MainActivity or the Activity1**:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.Init(this,bundle);
   }
```

Or you can use the following code in the **MainActivity or the Activity1** according to the [plugin document on the github](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin#version-4-major-update---android):

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        var activity = Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity;
        var context = Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.AppContext;
    }
```

In addition, there is a similar issue about [some errors after migrating from 4.0.2 to 6.7.0](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin/issues/515)  on the github, you can follow up it.